# Docker open a url in the host browser

Tags: docker

I have installed xdg-utils in my docker container using apt-get install xdg-utils

I want the command `xdg-open 'http://www.freedesktop.org/'` to open the specified url into the host browser.

right now it throws this error :

```
root@pravin:/# xdg-open 'http://www.freedesktop.org/'
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 778: /usr/bin/xdg-open: www-browser: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 778: /usr/bin/xdg-open: links2: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 778: /usr/bin/xdg-open: elinks: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 778: /usr/bin/xdg-open: links: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 778: /usr/bin/xdg-open: lynx: not found
/usr/bin/xdg-open: 778: /usr/bin/xdg-open: w3m: not found
xdg-open: no method available for opening 'http://www.freedesktop.org/'
```

How do I get docker to use the browser of the host os?

Answer (score 7):

This is possible by having the container communicate with a process outside of the container that can execute `xdg-open` on the host.

On the host, let's make a named pipe `hostbrowserpipe` and constantly poll it for new URLs that we should open:

```bash
mkfifo hostbrowserpipe
while read -r URL < hostbrowserpipe; do xdg-open "$URL"; done
```

Then let's run a container that writes to this pipe via a bind mount:

```bash
docker run --rm -v "$(pwd)"/hostbrowserpipe:/var/run/hostbrowserpipe alpine \
    sh -c "echo https://stackoverflow.com/a/73750272 >> /var/run/hostbrowserpipe"
```

---

Notes:

- On the host side, `DISPLAY` must be set for `xdg-open` to work. For example `export DISPLAY=:0` to use the primary display.
- This doesn't work with Docker Desktop on macOS and the `open` command.

Comment: This is a very unique answer, I like it.

Answer (score 3):

You can't, because container doesn't share with OS process/network namespace/filesystems by default.

In theory you can start container in the host process namespaces (`--pid=host`), network host namespace (`--network=host`) and mount required FS to the container (`--volume ..`), but still you may have another issues. That will require very advance Docker container skills.

Answer (score 1):

I think it may be hard to attach to host process and open new window.

There can be some solution that will overcome this difficulties. You can run browser process inside container and share display with host.

The main idea is to share `DISPLAY` environmental variable and network between host and container. More about this you can find in this great [article](https://medium.com/@SaravSun/running-gui-applications-inside-docker-containers-83d65c0db110) .

Comment: `DISPLAY` will be useful if browser is running in the container. But question mentioned browser from the host OS.

Answer (score 0):

I use [tmux-fzf-url](https://github.com/wfxr/tmux-fzf-url) inside a tmux session in the command line.
Pressing Prefix (by default `Ctrl+b` in tmux), then `Ctrl+u` searches links in the current buffer and a list is populated.

You can then fuzzy-search filter it, pressing Enter opens the browser via an internal `xdg-open` call.

If you launched the Docker session from within tmux, this will be executed on the host, not in Docker. That means you don't need anything else and it will "just work".